# jQuery Listen Only When Click Hold

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my console, my following script starts logging not only upon clicking your mouse wheel but also continues after you stop holding the mouse wheel button.

```
var mPosX,
    mPosY;

$(document).on('mousedown', function (e) {
    "use strict";
    if( e.which === 2 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mPosX = event.pageX;
        mPosY = event.pageX;
        $(document).mousemove(function(event){
            var CmPosX = event.pageX,
                CmPosY = event.pageX;
            console.log('Original X: ' + mPosX + ', New X: ' + CmPosX + ' | Original Y: ' + mPosY + ', New Y: ' + CmPosY);
        });
    }
});
```

How can I get my script to only log whilst the mouse wheel is held down and stop when you release?

Comment: Can you use 'click' event instead of 'mousedown'?

Comment: @KhorshedAlam I tried this however the logs only start after you release when using click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd store something in `mousedown` and `mouseup` that you can access in `mousemove`

```js
$(document).on({
  mousedown: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.which === 2)
      $(window).data('isDown', true).data('mPosX', e.pageX).data('mPosY', e.pageY);
  },
  mouseup: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.which === 2) 
      $(window).data('isDown', false);
  },
  mousemove: function(e) {
    if ($(window).data('isDown')) {
      var CmPosX = e.pageX,
          CmPosY = e.pageY,
          mPosX  = $(window).data('mPosX'),
          mPosY  = $(window).data('mPosY');

      console.log('Original X: '    + mPosX +
                  ', New X: '       + CmPosX +
                  ' | Original Y: ' + mPosY +
                  ', New Y: '       + CmPosY);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hold down mousewheel and move ...</p>
```

Comment: This is very nice. Thank you very much!